# Load node by value of a field and update value for another field

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to load a node by a value in a custom field (field_one) to change the value of another custom field (field_two) on that node.

I am using the following code to load the node:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->loadByProperties(['field_one' => $fieldValue]);
```

I am then trying to update the value of "field_two" using the following code:

```
if ($node = reset($nodes)) {

    $node->set('field_two', 'New value');
    $node->save();
}
```

The above results in the error "InvalidArgumentException: Field field_two is unknown... "

It works if I try to set the value of the title ( $node->set('title', 'New value') ) but I can't get it to work for custom fields?

Comment: You could have a content type that has field_one but not field_two.

Comment: Ok, so I need to add a content type (bundle) in my IF statement?

Comment: WOW.. I spent 8 hours trying to figure this out and all was missing was to specify the content type!

I was about to go insane.. Thanks a bunch! :D

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment by @No Sssweat I realized that I simply needed to specify a content type:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->loadByProperties(['field_one' => $fieldValue, 'type' => 'CONTENT_TYPE']);
```